# how to check if argument in mysql columns or not and return a value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want write a function to check if MySQL has these arguments or not

for example:

```
+--------+--------+
| source | target | 
+--------+--------+
| cat    | dog    |  
| dog    | cat    |
+--------+--------+
```

if I use MySQL language `WHERE source=='cat' AND target== 'dog'`

In php code need to return a value if here return value 1 else return 0

Comment: Please post the code you have so that we can help you figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: `==` is not an operator in mysql use `=` instead.

Comment: if we need to query the MySQL needs the function mysql_query() to execute the query , i need an argument to store the check result how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function check($src, $trg) {    
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE source='$src' AND target='$trg';");
    return mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0;
}

echo "'cat' as source & 'dog' as target: " . check('cat', 'dog');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for it,

```
 function check_value($column,$argument)
 {
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE $column = $argument");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
    {
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
     return 0;
    }
 }
```

Use this with passing the column name from database and the value you want to match it with

echo     $result = check_value( "source","cat");

> output =   1;

Comment: if you want multiple columns then you can check the value for an array and create a string to pass into where